# cocos2d-x java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No configs match configSpec

Tags: cocos2d-x

my android device is HUAWEI C8500S
Android Version:2.2.2
cocos2d-x version:2.1.1

i run my app on the Android phone ,not on the emulator.

bug log:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No configs match configSpec

thanks in advance!

Comment: I have this in emulator 4.3.1